# What is the use of initialize object through three different ways in Java?

Tags: java

I am working with Java as beginner i was following a tutorial (http://www.javatpoint.com/object-and-class-in-java) which states that there are three different way through which one can initialize an object into java.

1. By reference variable
2. By method
3. By constructor

My Question is that what is the significance of using three different method for a single task.

Example: 
1) Object and Class Example: Initialization through reference

```
 class Student{  
     int id;  
     String name;  
    }  
    class TestStudent2{  
     public static void main(String args[]){  
      Student s1=new Student();  
      s1.id=101;  
      s1.name="Sonoo";  
      System.out.println(s1.id+" "+s1.name);//printing members with a white space  
     }  
    }
```

2) Object and Class Example: Initialization through method

```
    class Student{  
     int rollno;  
     String name;  
     void insertRecord(int r, String n){  
      rollno=r;  
      name=n;  
     }  
     void displayInformation(){System.out.println(rollno+" "+name);}  
    }  
    class TestStudent4{  
     public static void main(String args[]){  
      Student s1=new Student();  
      Student s2=new Student();  
      s1.insertRecord(111,"Karan");  
      s2.insertRecord(222,"Aryan");  
      s1.displayInformation();  
      s2.displayInformation();  
     }  
    }
```

3) Object and Class Example: Initialization through constructor

```
class Employee{  
        int id;  
        String name;  
        float salary;  
        void insert(int i, String n, float s) {  
            id=i;  
            name=n;  
            salary=s;  
        }  
        void display(){System.out.println(id+" "+name+" "+salary);}  
    }  
    public class TestEmployee {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Employee e1=new Employee();  
        Employee e2=new Employee();  
        Employee e3=new Employee();  
        e1.insert(101,"ajeet",45000);  
        e2.insert(102,"irfan",25000);  
        e3.insert(103,"nakul",55000);  
        e1.display();  
        e2.display();  
        e3.display();  
    }  
    }
```

Comment: Ummm what?..... Do you have code example for for 1,2,3 to show what you mean by that, as I dont exactly what are you talking about

Comment: can you explain what exactly you need??

Comment: FWIW that looks like a pretty poor tutorial - it's telling you things that you *can* do, without going through why you would do them or the pros and cons of doing so.  And I can't imagine any situation where one would actually use "initialisation by reference variable" in the real world, it's *horrible*.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the significance of using three different method for a single task.

It's the same significance as any task in software development: there are often multiple ways of writing code that would result in the same eventual state, and so we consider which one of these is most appropriate.  Arguably (IMHO), this is the real skill of development: not simply being able to make the computer *do* a particular thing, but writing code to do that thing that is as simple/clean/understandable/extensible as it possibly can be.

In this specific case, I would **strongly** recommend initialising the fields through the constructor.  Sometimes it makes sense for an object's fields to be mutable, and to be initialised after the object is created (as in cases 1 and 2).  But in most cases - and especially here with "id" fields that define the object itself - it is clearest if the object is constructed with those fields.  This way there's no point where the object is in an invalid state; it's impossible to create an `Employee` object that has no `id`.

Note that what you've pasted for example 3 is **not** an example of constructor initialisation!  Read the page carefully, they say they will cover this later.  The code you've pasted is unrelated.

I would do something like the following:

```
class Student{  
  final int id;  
  final String name;  

  // This is the constructor that will initialise the fields with what's passed in
  // (Note that because the fields are final, they MUST be set by the constructor)
  public Student(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class TestStudent6 {  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
    Student s1 = new Student(101, "Sonoo");  
    System.out.println(s1.id + " " + s1.name); //printing members with a white space  
  }  
}
```

(Note that I'd probably also make the `id` and `name` fields private and set up `getId()` and `getName()` methods to access them instead, but that's outside the scope of what you asked.)

Comment: Sorry for that I just missed that line to read but if you forgot the third example my Question is significantly important for me to understand the basics. thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

Objects have `state` and its internal to it, hence it should be best made hidden from the outside i.e. not accessible to outside classes.  There will be other classes which may be dependent upon the object. Ideally these external classes should depend upon the public methods to modify or read the state. Hiding the internal details (states) and exposing only the needed methods is a good idea.

Now we have our fields encapsulated so in brief see initilization using constructor vs setters. If a class is composed of few fields without which an object of that class do not make sense, like a `MovingCar` is composed of `wheels` , so if there is a field `wheels` then it must be initilized along with the creation of object of `MovingCar`. These fields better are initilized through Constructors.  The other fields such as `musicSystem` may be initilized using setter methods.

Sometimes we may end up with so many constructors (overloaded) which may make it confusing for the users of such a class. Methods are better which can be named to let the users know the intention. Even better aaproach in such a case is `builder pattern`.